# Solving equation with fractional power law exponent

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

It is possible to solve analytically this kind of equation:
$$
a\cdot x^{\frac{4}{5}} - bx = c
$$
for $x$ ?

I thought about applying for both side logarithm with base equal $\frac{4}{5}$.
But what the next step should be? 
Or maybe it is not possible to solve this kind of equation by hand? 
I will be thankful for any clue and help.

Comment: This seems to be a quintic in $x^\frac{1}{5}$. I don't think there are analytical solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(1) \quad a \cdot x^{4/5}-b \cdot x=c$$

If you've never heard of [U-substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_variables). It's time to learn, it's very useful. Choose $u=x^{1/5}$ and substitute into $(1)$.

$$(2) \quad a \cdot (u^5)^{4/5}-b \cdot u^5=c$$

$$\Rightarrow u^4 \cdot (a-b \cdot u)=c$$

This could be solved, but it'd be very tedious and depend on the constants. I suggest [newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), if you know calculus, or [fixed point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration) for numerical values. Using the later we have,

$$u_{n+1}=\left(\cfrac{c}{a-b \cdot u_n} \right)^{1/4}$$

Which may converge for suitable choice of $u_0$ to *one* of the roots. You'd need to know a lot more about the subject to prove it converges. However, for $a=2$ $\ b=5$ and $c=7$ we have one of roots, of the original equation, given by,

$$\lambda=\cfrac{7^{5/4}}{\left(2-5 \cdot \left(\cfrac{7}{2-5 \cdot \left(\cfrac{7}{2-5 \cdot \left(\cfrac{7}{2-5 \ddots} \right)^{1/4}} \right)^{1/4}} \right)^{1/4} \right)^{5/4}}$$

Answer (score 0):

No, these don't allways have analytical solution, take a look at this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory,
set $ y = x^{1}{5}   $ then this equation becomes $ a\cdot y^4 - b\cdot y^5 - c = 0 $, which is a quintic function !

Answer (score 0):

Your equation is equivalent to a quintic of the form $x^5 + Ax + B = 0$, which is known as the [Bring–Jerrard form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Quintics_in_Bring.E2.80.93Jerrard_form). Analytical solutions to such equations may *sometimes* be found, depending on the coefficients. See the Wikipedia link for some information on how to determine if a particular equation can be solved that way.

However, if you're willing to use non-elementary functions, quintics can be solved analytically via Bring radicals, which are just the real roots of $t^5 + t - a=0$ for real $a$. And they can be solved using elliptic functions. Please see the Wikipedia article (and its links) for further details.